# Combine two tables and fill in missing values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables in MySQL:

Table 1:

```
ID Val1
1  100
2  200
3  300
```

Table 2:

```
ID Val2
2  50
```

How can I combine them into a table like this?

```
ID Val1 Val2
1  100  0
2  200  50
3  300  0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Val1, COALESCE(Table2.Val2, 0) AS Val2
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 USING (ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` in conjunction with `IFNULL()` to fill in zeros for Val2

```
SELECT 
  Table1.ID,
  Table1.Val1,
  IFNULL(Table2.Val2, 0) AS Val2
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Val1, COALESCE(Table2.Val2, 0) AS Val2
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 USING (ID)
INTO NewTable
```