# Doing a leftJoin to get missing values, but getting something other than zero for the values?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

A slight variant on the old leftJoin question:  I have two tables that I want to join:

```
ID Val1
1  100
2  200
3  300
```

and

```
ID Val2
2 50
```

Following [combine two tables and fill in missing values in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187182/combine-two-tables-and-fill-in-missing-values-in-mysql) and others, this:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Val1, COALESCE(Table2.Val2, 0) AS Val2
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 USING (ID)
```

will give me the usual result:

```
ID Val1 Val2
1  100  0
2  200  50
3  300  0
```

My question: Is there a way to get something other than zero as the missing values, perhaps:

```
ID Val1 Val2
1  100  9999
2  200  50
3  300  9999
```

I'd like to get the results ordered so that the items with missing values come at the end of the set; something like this would seem to let me do it (with some additional ORDER BY stuff,  of course).

Any thoughts?  If this can't be done, is there another way I can get the ordering the way I'd like?  Thanks!

Comment: You get whatever you put in the call to `COALESCE`. What do you think that's for?

Comment: You can also use `ORDER BY (Val2 != 0), Val2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COALESCE(Table2.Val2, 9999)` instead of `COALESCE(Table2.Val2, 0)`.

That's what COALESCE does, if the first expression is NULL then it sets the next expression.

If your main goal is to place the 0-valued rows at the bottom, and order the rest in ascending order, you can do the following.

```
SELECT 
  Table1.ID, 
  Table1.Val1, 
  COALESCE(Table2.Val2, 0) AS Val2
FROM Table1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 USING (ID)
ORDER BY 
  (CASE WHEN Table2.Val2 IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END), 
  Table2.Val2
```

This would produce a result set ordered like this:

```
ID Val1 Val2
2  200  50
1  100  0
3  300  0
```